# Change design of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to Android development and have recently started making apps with android studio.

Is it possible to change the look of the EditText component and how?

Here is the default look I'm getting when I create a new one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4pSV.jpg

And here is what I am trying to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/52PAg.jpg

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fivecore.nuqliati"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: You can try this simple library which is called [Float Labeled EditText](https://github.com/wrapp-archive/floatlabelededittext).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android floating labels were introduced in android design support library to display a floating label over EditText.

compile this library my friend

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+''
```

than add this code in your xml layout file

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email Address" />

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

for more information click here [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-floating-labels-for-edittext/)

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm still having trouble in compiling the library, how exactly do I do this?

Comment: please paste your gradle file or just paste your     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v--- which you used

Comment: Woops, that won't work, where should I paste my gradle file?

Comment: just paste thid depdency in you gradle app module file my friend

Comment: @LukaZdravkovic edit in your question my friend just simple

Comment: @LukaZdravkovic just check my update ans and change the depedenci

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+''

Answer (score 0):

For this type of design  android provides libraries that can change the look of your edittext

just use this textview

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:textColorHint="#4233FF" />
```

Dont forget to add this dependency to gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats called Android floating labels and You have to use TextInputLayout view for this use library

> compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

and you can use this in layout of view is

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:id="@+id/fname" />

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```